# Javascript Database ORM Design, circular dependency problem - Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access class before initialization

Tags: javascript, database, oop, orm, indexeddb

I'm trying to build simple database with ORM structure in javascript. Everything is based on IndexedDB. This is my concept:

1. Database constructor initilize database and mapps tables to classes:

```js
import config from '../config/database';

//...

config.models.forEach(model => {
   if(model.getModelName() === table.name){
       this[table.name].mapToClass(model);
   }
});
```

Config has models array with classes imported:

```js
import Population from "../models/Population";

export default {
    models: [
        Population, // this line throws error
        //...
    ],
};
```

Population model has methods which are getting database content:

```js
export default class Population extends Model{
    save() {
        return DB.population.put(this);
    }

    static all(){
        return DB.table('population');
    }
}
```

Then, when i try get Population.all(), i get this error (at database config file):

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Population$1' before initialization
```

Also, i have a warning about circular dependency Population.js. How to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to describe or include the code which throws the error

Comment: The error throws config file - in array, line with Population. I've edited post and pointed it.